# How to change C# class template to generate a lean starting class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

When I add a new class foo.cs (via Project/Add New Item), I would like to generate the following:

```
namespace MyNamespace;
public class foo
{
}
```

Instead, I get the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace;
internal class foo
{
}
```

The `using` statements are unnecessary through the magic of `ImplicitUsings`.  And I would like the class to be `public` instead of `internal`.

I've looked through the Options and various .editorconfig commands, but don't see anything obvious.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: @quaabaam It did!  Thank you.